# How do callback functions work in ts?

Tags: typescript

Good day. I'm new in ts and can't understand how callback functions work in ts. I have this expample:

```
this.signalRService.autocompletePerson((res => {
            console.log(res);
            if(this.surname != ""){
              this.dialogService.GetAutocomplite("surname-face-input", this.SetArrayToAutocomplite(res));
            }
            else if(this.surname == ""  ){
              this.name = "";
              this.otchestvo ="";
              this.age = "";
            }
        }).bind(this), { surname: this.surname});

public autocompletePerson(callback:(any) => void, personCard:any){
      var data:Array<CallAcceptanceFaceCard>;
         this.hubSignalRProxy.invoke('autocompletePerson', personCard ).done(function(variants){
                  console.log("done");
                  callback(variants);

        })
        .fail(function(err){
          console.log("err");
          console.log(err);
        });
```

The first quetion: is parameter `callback:(any) => void`made for `(res => { }` ?

The second: what implemets first `res => { }` or body of `autocompletePerson(callback:(any) => void, personCard:any)`?

And third: which part of code wait another to finish(of `res` and `autocompletePerson`)?

Comment: there are no such things as callback functions in ts. they're just plain old regular javascript functions. what you have there are some arrow functions from ES6 (all the => ). You can find out more about them on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @toskv, wow, thank u!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation after **callback** parameter in the **autocompletePerson** function defines the expected type of the parameter.

In this case `callback:(any) => void` means the **callback** parameter is expected to be a function that can take a parameter of type any and does not return.

When **autocompletePerson** is called it must receive such a function. In your case that function is:

```
res => {
        console.log(res);
        if(this.surname != ""){
          this.dialogService.GetAutocomplite("surname-face-input", this.SetArrayToAutocomplite(res));
        }
        else if(this.surname == ""  ){
          this.name = "";
          this.otchestvo ="";
          this.age = "";
        }
    }
```

Note: you don't need the **bind(this)** part because you are using an ES6 arrow function that typescript already compiles in such a way that the same lexical context is preserved.

As for the order of the calls it's this:

1. autocompletePerson
2. this.hubSignalRProxy.invoke
3. done // most likely finished later asynchronously
4. callback(res) // the function received as a parameter
5. everything in the callback